# C# + Querying XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning to use LINQ. I have seen some videos online that have really impressed me. In an effort to learn LINQ myself, I decided to try to write a query to the NOAA web service. If you put "http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdBrowserClientByDay.php?zipCodeList=20001&format=24+hourly&startDate=2010-06-10&numDays=5" in your browser's address bar, you will see some XML. I have successfully retrieved that XML in a C# program. I am loading the XML into a LINQable entity by doing the following:

```
string xml = QueryWeatherService();
XDocument weather = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

I have a class called DailyForecast defined as follows:

```
public class DailyForecast
{
  public float HighTemperature { get; set; }    
  public float LowTemperature { get; set; }
  public float PrecipitationPossibility { get; set; }
  public string WeatherSummary { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying write a LINQ query that adheres to the structure of my DailyForecast class.  At this time, I've only gotten to this far:

```
var results = from day in response.Descendants("parameters") 
              select day;
```

Not very far I know. Because of the structure of the XML returned, I'm not sure it is possible to solely use a LINQ query. I think the only way to do this is via a loop and traverse the XML. I'm seeking someone to correct me if I'm wrong. Can someone please tell me if I can get results using purely LINQ that adhere to the structure of the DailyForecast class? If so, how?

Thank you!

Comment: linq will work fine, but if you already have some classes to target that match the shape of the input xml, you might consider using XmlSerializer with those types to just deserialize the input

Answer (score 1):

Since your xml may return multiple records,

```
var results = from day in response.Descendants("parameters") 
              select new DailyForecast()
              {
                 HighTemperature = day.Element("param name corresponding to high temp"),
              };

return result.ToList(); //or any type of collection you want to return
```